# 2015 ford 6.7 no start was running fine now it cranks but no fuel?

Tags: ford, fuel-system, pressure

I just got a 2015 superiority. It was driving fine. I shut it off now it cranks but won't start. Sounds like no compression, Yen I spray start fluid it starts for a sec then dies

Comment: Have you checked the fuse(s) for the fuel pump?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is that supposed to be a "2015 *Super Duty*"? Also, is this a diesel engine?